# Как правильно использовать React-router в моем случаи?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

Такая ситуация: Есть главная страница `index.html`, на ней вообще не используется `React`, на главной странице есть ссылка на страницу на которой используется `React`.

Мне нужно вывести мое приложение на странице на которой используется React, но видимо `webpack` настроен так, что он ищет контейнер только в `index.html`. Мне посоветовали использовать `React-router`, я в книге вычитал немного об этом, но там говориться немного о другом, там говорится о выводе на странице определенного компонента в зависимости от адреса страницы. Это не совсем то, что мне нужно.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import ElectronApp from './components/ElectronApp';

import {
 HashRouter,
 Route
} from 'react-router-dom'


ReactDOM.render(
 <HashRouter>
  <Route path="/electron-game.html" component={ElectronApp} />
 </HashRouter>,
 document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Вот мой код, он естественно не работает, как нужно, все что мне требуется, чтобы приложение выводилось не в `index.html`, а в `electron-game.html`, возможно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем ясно что Вы хотите получить.

Результатом скомпилированного реакт-проекта будет папка `/build`, где точкой входа будет `/build/index.html`. Если у Вас используется какой то сборщик всего в один проект, то можно слить реакт-приложение в корневую папку при этом переименовав `index.html` в `electron-game.html`:

```
/
  -- index.html
  -- about.html
  -- contacts.html
  -- electron-game.html (переименованный index.html из папки /build)
  -- /static (файлы реакт проекта)
  ---- /css
  ---- /js
  ---- /media
...
```

Например командой:

```
mv ./build/index.html ./build/electron-game.html && mv ./build ./
```